# NSUnknownKeyException error with UILabel swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsunknownkeyexception

I keep getting this error with regards to a UILabel I have setup in a new class. `'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7ff9c255d120> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key winnerLabel.'` (winnerLabel is the name of the UILabel). I have ensured that the class the ViewController's class is correct (in Main.storyboard>Select controller>Utility Area>Identity Inspector>Class). From asking around I have been told that 'The outlet name that's in the xib is out of sync with the name in the class,' if this is the case then how would I go about updating the the outlet's name in the xib/ storyboard. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: My question has been marked as a duplicate of another question. I have already explained that my problem was not solved by the answer to that question (^^^"I have ensured that the class the ViewController's class is correct (in Main.storyboard>Select controller>Utility Area>Identity Inspector>Class).

Comment: Unfortunately, gold tag badge owners are doing their tasks often a little bit unpredictable. Write in a comment clearly, why it is _not_ a duplicate, it significantly improves your chances. You got my reopen vote, but 5 is required for reopen. Over 150 reputation you can vote to reopen your question, too.

Comment: I still think it is a duplicate, and the second answer in the dupe explains the reason. If you think it is not a duplicate, just stating "it isn't" is not enough. It seems your controller class just doesn't have a winnerLabel property.